# Calling SOAP service returns WSDL

Tags: java, soap, soap-client, saaj

I'm trying to call VisualSoft Soap Test WS .. but every time i try to execute the request .. it returns their Default **WSDL** although of the SOAP working properly if i used an external tool for testing .

What's the mistake that i made ? :

Code :

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    try {
        // Create SOAP Connection
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

        // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server.
        String url = "https://demo.visualsoft.co.uk/api/soap/wsdl/3";

        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), new URL(url));

        // Process the SOAP Response
        printSOAPResponse(soapResponse);

        soapConnection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}



private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
    String xml = "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ns1=\"http://demo.visualsoft.co.uk/api/soap/service\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:SOAP-ENC=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\"><SOAP-ENV:Header><ns1:VSAuth><ClientID>testclient</ClientID><Username>testuser</Username><Password>testpass</Password></ns1:VSAuth></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:HelloWorld/></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";

    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    MimeHeaders Headers = new MimeHeaders();

    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage(Headers, is);
    soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);

    return soapMessage;
}

private static String convertDocumentToString(Document doc) {
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer;
    try {
        transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(writer));
        String output = writer.getBuffer().toString();
        return output;
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

private static void printSOAPResponse(SOAPMessage soapResponse) throws Exception {
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
    System.out.println("Response SOAP Message = ");
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
    transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);
}
```

More Details about the SOAP : https://demo.visualsoft.co.uk/api/soap#WSDL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request should be sent to `https://demo.visualsoft.co.uk/api/soap/service/3` as denoted in the `service` of the WSDL.

Comment: Thaaaaanks !... one more inquiry dear , is there any way to process SoapClient in Java like its sample on PHP ? i mean to pass the operation and the arguments only as parameters instead of sending the whole XML Format ?

Answer (score 0):

Bottom my sample with this title "Java Client for Weather service open source webservice avaliable on http://www.webserviceX.NET" explains how to call webservice and and build soap request xml in java:

```
 package com.test.ws.example;

 import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
 import javax.xml.soap.MimeHeaders;
 import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
 import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection;
 import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory;
 import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;
 import javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
 import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
 import javax.xml.soap.SOAPPart;
 import javax.xml.transform.Source;
 import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
 import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
 import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

 /*
  * WSDL url :  http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?WSDL
  * Endpoint URL: http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx   */

 public class WSClient {

   public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

        // Generate SOAP request XML

        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        MimeHeaders header = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        header.setHeader("SOAPAction", "http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetCitiesByCountry");
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("web", "http://www.webserviceX.NET");
        SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("GetCitiesByCountry", "web");
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("CountryName", "web");
        soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("INDIA");
        soapMessage.saveChanges();
        soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);


        // Call webservice endpint
        String url = "http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx";
        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapMessage, url);
        Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();

        // Print SOAP response
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        System.out.println("Response SOAP Message \n");
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);
        soapConnection.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```